# POST vs GET при использовании в CRM

Tags: php, безопасность

В самописной CRM все действия деструктивного характера (удаление, например) сделал через POST запрос. Так как считал, что его тяжелее подделать пользователю, чем GET запрос. Сейчас же задумался, а стоит ли оно того: тянуть либо форму для отправки, либо Js скрипты, когда можно сделать просто ссылку, при условии, что все действия (деструктивные) и так протоколируются.

Как вы считаете, моя паранойя обоснована или нет?

З.Ы. под пользователем подразумевается сотрудник организации, а не клиент.

Comment: А браузеры уже перестали подгружать контент заранее по ссылкам на открытой странице? :)

Comment: да я вообще первый раз слышу, что они это умеют. Теперь в курсе, буду знать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> В самописной CRM все действия деструктивного характера (удаление, например) сделал через POST запрос. Так как считал, что его тяжелее подделать пользователю, чем GET запрос. Сейчас же задумался, а стоит ли оно того: тянуть либо форму для отправки, либо Js скрипты, когда можно сделать просто ссылку, при условии, что все действия (деструктивные) и так протоколируются.
>
> Как вы считаете, моя паранойя обоснована или нет?

Скажем так, разумно обоснована. Если пользователь хочет кривым путем дотянуться до ручки удаления - он все равно это сделает, если ему не перекрывать доступ через авторизацию. Но что касается всяких автоматических систем - они действительно пользуются спецификацией HTTP, согласно которой метод GET является *идемпотентным* и *безопасным*, т.е. *производимый им результат (получение данных) не зависит от количества вызовов* и *его вызов не приводит к изменению данных*, поэтому GET-запрос по любой найденной ссылке можно производить без каких-либо сомнений. Лично я никогда не сталкивался с тем, чтобы робот проходил по удаляющим ссылкам, но слышал историю от одного из участников такой истории, что в одной большой и всем известной компании робот однажды грохнул небольшую (~600 записей, забитых вручную) БД сотрудников. Поэтому лучше обезопаситься и сделать всё красиво, не предоставляя пользователям ручки на изменение данных путем GET-запроса.

Другое дело, что POST-запросы зесь на самом деле тоже не годятся. Пять основных методов HTTP (из девяти описанных в спецификации) - это HEAD (получить сведения о ресурсе), GET (получить ресурс полностью), POST (**создать ресурс**), PUT (заменить ресурс) и DELETE (удалить ресурс). В идеале все запросы на удаление должны идти через DELETE, это не только соблюдет семантику, но и поднимет вас по REST-лестнице этажом выше.

Comment: REST - это хорошо. Как жаль, что в php нет явной поддержки `$_PUT` и `$_DELETE` со всеми вытекающими.

Comment: @ArchDemon $_GET и $_POST на самом деле не несут никакой связи с get и post. $_GET - результат парсинга query string,  $_POST - результат парсинга тела запроса, обе штуки теоретически могут быть при любом запросе; $_POST можно хоть вручную заполнять с помощью `php://input`.

Answer (score 0):

Все действия, которые действительно что-то меняют на сайте, должны быть реализованы через POST. Причин множество, основные, на мой взгляд:

- GET-запросы кэшируются по умолчанию. Если вы сделаете действие через GET - оно может просто не дойти до сервера, пользователь получит закэшированный результат. Особенно весело ловить такие проблемы в IE - при открытии Dev Tools он перестает кэшировать, и начинает работать "по честному". При незнании об этой фишке можно провести в попытках воспроизвести баг "у меня не работает!" несколько увлекательных часов.
- Браузеры любят превентивно подгружать потенциальные результаты GET-запросов. Т.е. пока пользователь будет задумчиво водить мышкой над ссылкой удалить - заботливый Chrome за него сходит по ссылке и действительно удалит объект. На всякий случай - а вдруг пользователь захочет на нее нажать! :)

Comment: на моей памяти у хрома никогда не было превентивной подгрузки, кроме как по урлам из омнибокса

Comment: @Etki хром чисто для примера. урлы из омнибокса - уже достаточно серьезное зло.

Comment: @Etki и он все-таки иногда подгружает именно кликабельные ссылки - https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1385029?hl=en -  Google Chrome does this by predicting what links you might *click*

Comment: *урлы из омнибокса - уже достаточно серьезное зло* - ну да, я часто пользуюсь одной и той же ссылкой на удаление, поэтому когда в стопидесятый раз она будет вызвана не вручную, а автоматически, это вызовет необратимые изменения. *Google Chrome does this by predicting what links you might click* - без явной подсказки со стороны страницы он этого делать не будет: *The blog can tell Google Chrome to pre-load the “next post,” so the page shows instantly when you click it.*

Comment: @Etki ссылка на удаление может быть и по индексу в гриде. и даже для недеструктивных действий -  ссылка может доставлять *неудобства*, даже если не удаляет данные. зафетчит Chrome какой-нибудь /Messages/MarkAllAsRead - манагер пропустит сообщение от клиента, потом еще раз, и еще раз. и манагера уволят. а у него, жена, дети, кредитный форд фокус и ипотека. а вы по логам будете смотреть и говорить "да, этот чел вообще не читает входящие, так ему и надо!"